# Let $ D $ be an Euclidean domain and $d$ be the associated function. $u$ is a unit in $D$ if and only if $d(u)=d(1)$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Since $u$ is a unit, $uv=1$ for some $v \in D$. Now $$d(1)=d(uv) \leq d(u)$$ Again $d(u) \leq d(uv)=d(1)$. Hence $d(u)=1$. BUT what about its converse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $u \in D$ with $d(u)=d(1)$.

Write $1=uq+r$ with $r=0$ or $d(r)< d(u)$.

If $r\ne0$, then $d(r)< d(u)=d(1) \le d(r\cdot1)=d(r)$, a contradiction.

Hence $r=0$ and $1=uq$, which proves that $u$ is a unit.

Comment: And it is assumed here that u is nonzero....that's why we can talk of d(u)...